# Having an issue with VT-x not being detected

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, intel-core-i7

I've recently built a new machine, planned as a significant upgrade from my last box...

- [Gigabyte X99P-SLI](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5658#ov) Motherboard
- [Intel i7-5930K](http://ark.intel.com/products/82931/Intel-Core-i7-5930K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz) CPU (Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x): Yes)
- 64 GB RAM
- Windows 10 Enterprise
- No Avast (or any AV except windows defender)
- Hyper-V is not installed (Although it was at one point, apparently thanks to Visual Studio)

I've enabled VT-x and VT-d in the BIOS.

CPU Z Output:

[image]

Securable Output:

[image]

What am I missing? How can I get Windows to detect virtualisation?

Comment: Ah yes... A commentless downvote. Must be a trilogy site.

Comment: Yeah I wonder how/why that happens, this is a perfectly good question and certainly doesn't deserve a down-vote. So I've up-voted. And I'm looking into this for you...

Comment: Its also notable that Securable has not been updated since 2007. many utilities work fine after that much drift, but many don't. The latest version of windows it states explicitly to support is Vista.

Comment: @misha256 Thank you. FrankThomas; I hadn't seen/used it before but other answers with a similar problem here on SU suggested it (I didn't check the date).